# Plot a graph point to point python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I wonder if there is some way to plot a waveform point to point at a certain rate through the matplotlib so that the graph appears slowly in the window. Or another method to graph appears at a certain speed in the window and not all the points simultaneously. I've been tried this but I can only plot a section of points at a time

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

x = np.arange(0,5,0.001)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

ind_i = 0
ind_f = 300


while ind_f <= len(x):

    xtemp = x[ind_i:ind_f]
    ytemp = y[ind_i:ind_f]

    plt.hold(True)
    plt.plot(xtemp,ytemp)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(1)    

    ind_i = ind_f
    ind_f = ind_f + 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with Matplotlib's FuncAnimation function. Adapting [one of the matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/examples/animation/basic_example.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.arange(0,5,0.001)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()

data = np.vstack((x,y))
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line, frames=1000,
                           fargs=(data, l), interval=20, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow! It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, @xnx!